Identify unknown component marked t07
I have a eMachines 443 motherboard with a problem...power is not going to the battery.
I am trying to trace the circuit but encounter a few unknown components. What are this part marked "t07"?


Please refer to the component identification guidelines. We request that you post only one component per question, and put the marking code in the title to allow better search indexing.

Answering your first component marking, t07 will be a "PNP resistor-equipped transistor" - part number PDTA144EU from Nexperia (or similar).

This is a small SC-70 (smaller than SOT-23) package, with markings indicated per the datasheet and shown in an example photograph of the part found via search engine.


Image Source

thanks tom
i'll put up 2 more questions for the other 2 components.
Also, where did you find the link to this component??

@moshejay Just searching a well known search engine. In this case I looked up "SC-70 T07", knowing that SC-70 is the next smaller package from SOT-23 (experience). I also vaguely recognised the funky t from other NXP parts.

thanks tom
the well known search engine being?...google?
your knowledge is awesome.

@moshejay yes  Google
